# How to import partial attributes/variables without namespace of submodules in python?

Tags: python, module

### package tree

```sh
.
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── fun.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── __init__.py
```

#### content of `a/__init__.py`

```py
from .b import  fun
```

### content of `a/b/__init__.py`

```py
from .fun import  fun
```

#### content of `a/b/fun.py`

```py
def fun:
    print(111)
```

I just run `ipython`, and run

```
In [1]: import a                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: dir(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: 
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'b',
 'fun']

In [3]:
```

### issue

**The issue is i don't want 'b' in a's dir. I expect the package just export 'fun'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify `a/__init__.py` as below:

```py
from .b import  fun
del(b)
```